# Firebase Invites contact List

Tags: android, xml, contacts, google-contacts-api, firebase-invites

The documentation of Firebase Invite https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/ says that "The share screen's contact list is populated from the user's Google Contacts and the contacts stored locally on the device.".

In my app that i'm developing i see only Google Contact although i give it the permission to read contact storede locally writing in AndroidManifest.xml:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`

What am I missing?